# How to show only part of an int in c# (like cutting off a part of a credit card number)

Tags: c#

If I have a credit number that is an int and I just want to display the last 4 numbers with a * on the left, how would I do this in C#?

For example, 4838382023831234 would shown as *1234

Comment: For the record, credit card numbers probably should be strings to begin with so that you never potentially have an overflow. 16 digits = 1,000,000,000,000,000; which will overflow anything short of an Int64. You're never (I hope) going to do arithmetic on them, so you might consider them strings which just HAPPEN to be numeric in nature.

Comment: So true John the example he has actually couldn't be an int its to big

Comment: It's also quite possible that your credit card number could start with a 0.

Comment: Good point.  I made it a string.

Comment: @John, or you could just change it to a `Int64` and save on the database storage space over a `string`, and the arithmetic you may want to do is to validate it through an implementation of the Luhn or Verhoeff algorithms. If you use a proper implementation, it will accept the `Int64` (not a `string`) right off the bat without the need for string conversion and thereby perform faster. A number is a number, *don't* treat it as a string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
// assumes that ccNumber is actually a string
string hidden = "*" + ccNumber.Substring(ccNumber.Length - 4);
```

Comment: +1 for seeing the reasoning behind the question, and not simply answering the question as asked. Nice one :)

Answer (score 18):

If it's an integer type?

Where i is the int

```
string maskedNumber = string.Format("*{0}", i % 10000)
```

This will get the modulus of 10,000 which will return the last four digits of the int

Comment: A thousand apologies m'dear :)

Comment: Max int is "2147483647" which is 10 characters, max UInt64 is "18446744073709551615" which is sufficient. If you already have the number as a string, you're better off taking one of the other answers that directly manipulate a string. Your question did say "if I hve a credit number that is an int" . . .

Comment: P.S. The thousand apologies were for annakata, it's not often I pip folks at the post, normally the other way around :)

Answer (score 5):

```
string myCc = myCc.ToString().Substring(12).PadLeft(1, '*');
```

Comment: You're going to assign that to an int?

Answer (score 2):

A credit card number will overflow an int32 and just like phone numbers it doesn't make any sense to think about adding, subtractings, or multiplying credit card numbers. Also string inputs can handle formatting because some users will write in the hyphens. For those reasons, its a lot better to store these objects as strings and reserve numeric value types for data that you actually intend to perform arithmetic on.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not satisfied.

***binaryworrier***: Mind that if you use modulo, you will get fewer digits for numbers such as
1234123412340001

***sshow***: mind that, if you use substring(12), you will get fewer digits for numbers such as
0000123412341234

solution would be:

```
UInt64 ccNumber;
string s = ccNumber.ToString().Text.PadLeft(15, 'myString');
string last = "*"+s.Substring(s.Length-4);
```

But on a more abstract note, is a credit card number actually a number?
I think not; much more likely that you are going to want to manipulate it digit by digit than perform arithmetic on it. Your advantage of converting char[16] to UInt64 cuts storage space by 50%. No wait, 75% - stupid two-byte-chars!

Answer (score 1):

If the number is stored as a string then this will do it

```
    string ccNumber = "4242424242424242";
    string modifiedCCNumber = "*" + ccNumber.Substring(ccNumber.Length - 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string cardNo = "1234567890123456";
string maskedNo = "*" + cardNo.Substring(12,4);
```