# How to String.Format an Int64 into an 'obfuscated' string (for a Credit Card) C#?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Say I have an `Int64` = `1234567890123456` (and we assume its a valid number), how can I format it into `1••• •••• •••• 3456`?

I've tried `String.Format("{0:#••• •••• •••• ####}")` and `String.Format("{0:0••• •••• •••• 0000}")` and both of them produce `123456789012••• •••• •••• 3456` which is wrong and completely defeats the point of obfuscating the number...

I'd appreciate some guidance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you *have* to use `string.Format` instead of just using a method?

Comment: Very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773396/how-to-show-only-part-of-an-int-in-c-like-cutting-off-a-part-of-a-credit-card-n

Comment: how about a simple string substitution?

Comment: I tried converting to string, but I must have been spacing out or something because it wasn't producing what I wanted. I don't really care which way its done...

Comment: I would use a securestring instead of an int to handle sensitive data - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx

Comment: @Laurent, a `SecureString` is not really the way I want to go. I just want to take the `Int64` that I have and format it in an 'obfuscated' form for display purposes *only*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to just convert it to a string and fill in the specific chars?

```
string strNum = num.ToString().PadLeft(16,'0');
for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++) strNum[i] = '*';
```

something along those lines?

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing a slightly more complex version of your example, but it does the job.