# how to show only the last four digit of a credit card number

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show only part of an int in c# (like cutting off a part of a credit card number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773396/how-to-show-only-part-of-an-int-in-c-sharp-like-cutting-off-a-part-of-a-credit)

I want to display a string in which only the last four digit of the Credit Card # are shown. Also I want to show the reason description.

The credit card number is inputted in the "textbox1"
the value reason description is taken from the combobox "cmbreason"

I want to show the string-> "Received returned card ending in (last 4 cc #) due to (reason) Will dispose off after 45 days"

The string is passed to the variable noteline1.

How will I achieve it? Please help!

Comment: Not sure with your question you can try "####" + append by pulling out the last 4 from the string/textbox which contains the card number

Comment: So what do you actually don't know how do? How to get last 4 digits from `noteline1`(guys have already answered)? Or do not know how to displaythis value on GUI?

Comment: I input the credit card number as well as the reason description in a textbox. From their I want to pass a string to the data member "noteline1" of the requestdata contract of a service. The string should contains the last 4 digit of the credit card and the reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a combination of [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) and [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d).

---

**Example:**

```
var card_number = "1234384234034";
var reason = "some reason";
var s = "Received returned card ending in {0} due to {1} will dispose off after 45 days";
var text = String.Format(s, card_number.Substring(card_number.Length-4), reason);
```

---

**Output:**

> Received returned card ending in 4034 due to some reason will dispose off after 45 days

Comment: Of course this promotes the storing the credit card as plaintext which is not very secure.

Answer (score 3):

to get the last 4 characters of a string

```
var last4 = ccNo.Substring(ccNo.Length-4,4);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/OEH45563